# Is it possible to create a new Docker image from a Docker Container that has been utilized?

Tags: docker

Example:

Create Docker container for a Wordpress Instance. Use the Wordpress instance by adding blog posts, pages, plugins, etc.

Generate a new Docker Image based on that exact Docker Container so that the image contains all of the blog posts, pages, plugins, etc.

Now create a new container from that image so that when it springs from the loins of Docker it has all of the blog posts, pages, plugins, etc.

and if not...how would you suggest getting to this outcome?

Thanks!

Comment: The Docker [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial walks through the standard process of building an image using a Dockerfile; you can commit this to source control and rebuild the image if you need to.  In the particular case of the [Docker Hub `wordpress` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) it's constructed in a way that you can't create a derived image with preloaded content, either through `docker build` or `docker commit`.

Comment: Thanks, David. I'm pretty new to Docker and still trying to make sure its the right path for what I'm trying to do. Your links are helpful.

From this comment, and the one on the other answer, are you saying that what I describe IS possible but you suggest building out Dockerfile that contains everything? Thanks.

Comment: It should be, but you might not be able to reuse some of the available prebuilt parts.  Logically there are separate layers of "the language runtime", "Wordpress", the customizations you describe here, and actual user content; I think the last two items get stored in the same directory tree and so it could be tricky to manage the storage but still make it possible to migrate an existing container's data on to a newer image.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible using command `docker commit container_name image_name:image_tag`.

The documentation for the command can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/). There's also a very comprehensive article on the subject [here](https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/).

Comment: I generally do not consider it a best practice to use `docker commit` at all.  In the OP's case, say there's a security vulnerability in the underlying Wordpress installation; there's no way they can update the base image without manually re-running all of their customizations on top of it.  Scripting this in a `Dockerfile` is a much better approach.

Comment: I agree, but the OP didn't ask whether it was a good idea, but whether it was possible at all.